# boot2docker behind proxy - certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, docker, proxy, boot2docker

I have installed DockerToolbox-1.12.0.exe on Windows 7. The corporate proxy provides its own certificate to do MITM.

I have configured boot2docker to use the proxy by exporting environment variables in .profile.

I am still not able to do

docker run hello-world

as i am getting - docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

Please anyone help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the MITM cert under the boot2docker/certs/ directory formatted as a PEM file? https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/347#issuecomment-222743070

Comment: i tried several solutions, all i get is 
docker: Could not reach any registry endpoint.